# Decompress and decrypt .png file

Tags: encryption, compression, png

I have a multiple .png file, compressed (i guess) and encrypted with RC4, I fugired dencrypt them if has 02 flag but some of files have a 03 flag for this reason i can't sure what should I  do with them.

I created small script for files keys come from older version of libRedAlert.so file attached link belong newer version of the file.

How can I dencrypt files with 03 header ?

```
goto 2
get tur byte

goto 3
get boyut byte
set boyutint byte boyut
print "%boyutint%"


if tur == 2 
if boyut = 0
set KEY binary "BHnvp0MzjCkWQFqKmV8UcAkp7UIijyYu"

elif boyut = 1
set KEY binary "vpdLsd2Wb24ViPZytJrpqyTf9P6AOscV"

elif boyut = 2
set KEY binary "isoEmK7iFG1dbqrxqFTJzg1C9W1dIyqt"

elif boyut = 3
set KEY binary "exlirtfDws3ARqhSuGwBjpgUf4fZlFng" 

elif boyut = 4
set KEY binary "wpbOslaZ7yoSIhTAqL5GQvzpreafUyIB" 

elif boyut = 5
set KEY binary "NC247A9468oIbN06Dl33bAWNRT564G6h" 

elif boyut = 6
set KEY binary "KEMM57pmw5tlNwd8mXVWzknFtoPZC1kW" 

elif boyut = 7
set KEY binary "82UWUczlZ7lRF7UHp5IIhk6vWDDtF9TN" 

elif boyut = 8
set KEY binary "Y2GjxmxZf6tybbnsToL2yDXIM78gPFIz" 

elif boyut = 9
set KEY binary "YhynPDvwXGOCRdcfh0MqOA45L4NxOK9H" 

elif boyut = 10
set KEY binary "ePLkqVjpC2J5xMNWMg5UeQRmuVuqd2fK" 

elif boyut = 11
set KEY binary "dwkwTHXGV3gUP8ruVz82lE9bl4hOzMca" 

elif boyut = 12
set KEY binary "Vm803WsmeAzoKSehjwk58vC9BKzpCa97" 

elif boyut = 13
set KEY binary "onlqzhRdk5DXEUxDNl2ycOxgOiqYRV7N" 

elif boyut = 14
set KEY binary "jD53QsARsnfToMEFGtRQf2DttA9VlfjM" 

elif boyut = 15
set KEY binary "2tjc6ZYSzPcDL4BmqyajRYiGRMc3LQDM" 

elif boyut = 16
set KEY binary "O40LK56qOAN77cgSntQpqj2Jed7CFjkw" 

elif boyut = 17
set KEY binary "89v8YQPXlgwtmpN5SPoaqqaV7F3A4O60" 

elif boyut = 18
set KEY binary "w5fdDE8ckG1U2WfrCx90OoGv5NecaQhV" 

elif boyut = 19
set KEY binary "r6BRiUCtaYkTOCn29NPAUlwGyOQLvrli" 

elif boyut = 20
set KEY binary "wO4oHSn71Xkz8uOSM5i8e3YFTw9D9sHw" 

elif boyut = 21
set KEY binary "Y1FweX2iDHsn7UsuzKAQNBi5TrLBjgBu" 

elif boyut = 22
set KEY binary "lHxpT130gjF0KH1JJvgDABNBnkhj6yu1"

elif boyut = 23
set KEY binary "ohXYm9jjX5HyfHZRamO9ijQO3Pa7ysoD" 


elif boyut = 24
set KEY binary "mcozkxPR9NrTPsHPjPwVioskHvJ60XMn" 


elif boyut = 25
set KEY binary "oAWP9EYBjjKoyfITbftSSxSduXzpyrt8" 

elif boyut = 26
set KEY binary "cp0EEIES1nnMukpnIsQ3GByDKn7FRCUY" 

elif boyut = 27
set KEY binary "6D8HhjTzdJ9ndmVNlHoByUkBF9vTfAGU" 

elif boyut = 28
set KEY binary "7LfUsmIGJttnldf8QJhYnLSgCVCsYefO" 

elif boyut = 29
set KEY binary "wH0m8i550z5DCXxrog4npkldpKspIPVA" 

elif boyut = 30
set KEY binary "rDsnIrlu9KUxV3PBPB0AJyl6YvK0rT9D" 

elif boyut = 31
set KEY binary "UqVR7MFIbxn8MQRsnvzOVB6yjJJrrkZy" 

else
print "Something wrong"
endif

print "%KEY%"

goto 4
get size long
savepos offset
encryption rc4 KEY

#math SIZE - OFFSET

get NAME basename
string NAME += ".png"
log NAME offset size


endif
```

[keys.so file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dhIbd2vKxEwnc1WRSlPbgWIYTPbdXoue/view?usp=sharing)

[example file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WjTSCZFAxAd9YUsQBSQ6-pkQf0JMZOo4) -This one works with program
[example file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1loghIV2YSAcn-uoGEHykGlMzAqIoPWwI) -This one not works with program

[image: guide]

Comment: And.. what is the question? Please read and folow the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide to get any reasonable answer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question, it's about decryption a particular (unknown) file and therefore of no use to anybody else.